# How android handles images on different screens

Tags: android, image, screen, image-scaling, image-size

I am new to android development area and I am finding it hard to understand how images are handled on different screen resolutions. I have read the developer documentation and also gone through various SO questions but none of them have addressed my question or rather I have missed or failed to understand. What my question is , suppose I have an application which uses
images that are stored on the server and my application is being used on different phones having different screen resolutions , but the image that is on the server is of some fixed resolution. How will the android system will handle displaying this image on my screen?
Is it something that my application should handle or android system will scale the image as per my screen configuration. My image on the server never changes and is of the fixed size and I have allocated some space on the screen of my application to display it.

Comment: First read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Android scales the image to fit each screen size/density, this is the purpose of the drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdp, etc.. folders. So is your job to get the same image in diferent sizes to fit them correctly to diferent divices.

Comment: But my image is stored on a server and not locally in my application
every time the app is launched , it goes to the server and then fetches it, In that case how is it done?

Comment: In that case it gets that image and resizes it to fit the device. If the devices densite/resolution is higher than the image's, the image will be seen pixeled